# Testing a React component that accepts a useState function as a prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm working on a test that is passed a useState function from the calling page

```
<InlineEdit
text={measure.name}
onSetText={(text) => setMeasure({ ...measure, name: text })}
/>
```

When I create this in test, I'm not sure how to create that function.  I'm stubbing something like below, but obviously teh function isn't going to do anything.

setMeasure is defined with
`const [measure, setMeasure] = useState<Measure>({ id: "", name: "" });`

My test is simply

```
test("Renders the InlineEdit 'View' span when state is false", () => {
  Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
  const baseProps = {
    text: "Name",
    onSetText: () => {() => {}}
  };
  const wrapper = render(<InlineEdit  {...baseProps}/>);
  
  ...
});
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you testing? That the `onSetText` is called? If so, what triggers the calling of it? The `InlineEdit` component probably shouldn't be concerned with whether the function is a `useState` or not. **Edit** I'd simply use a `jest.fn()` and assert that it was called.

Comment: Thanks.  I started down that route, but jest.fn() doesn't want to play nice with Typescript.

Comment: I use `jest.fn()` a lot with TypeScript. What issues did you have?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @DeanJames. Unfortunately, I've already forgotten what troubles I was experiencing when I posted this #facepalm.  All I remember is that when I looked up the issue, I found some posts that suggested that jest.fn() had troubles with Typescript.